# Random EJB connection failure from JSF bean to EJB

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm running a web application using the JSF framework and a separate application server that exposes EJBs.
What I'm trying to do is to interact with the EJBs from JSF managed beans but I receive an expeption like:

> No EJB receiver available for handling [...] combination for
>   invocation context
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@4d8d3512

This happens when I try to call a method on the EJB proxy retrieved using the JNDI lookup.

There are two interesting facts:

1. This happens most of the times but sometimes it actually works without exceptions
2. If I call the same EJB method from outside a JSF managed bean (for example from a simple Servlet) it works all the times

So this may have something to do with the JSF beans lifecycle.

This is the JSF bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserMgr {

    IManager mgr;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            // JNDI lookup for EJB with IManager interface
            mgr = ServiceLocator.getRemoteService(IManager.class);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public UserDTO getUser(long uid) {
        //This call throws the exception (sometimes)
        return mgr.getUser(uid);
    }
}
```

I'm using JSF 2.2 on GlassFish 4.1

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just, you know, `@EJB`-in your `IManager`? You *are* using the latest version of everything. The service locator pattern is superfluous here

Comment: Yes that would be the most reasonable solution, however this is part of an assignment in which I have to use the service locator pattern.